# Не получается очистить canvas рисовалку

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Не получается очистить холст, не хватает какой-то простой доработки. Подскажите пожалуйста какой

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var myColor = "#fff";
ctx.fillStyle = "gray";
ctx.fillRect(10, 10, 400, 250);
let clearButton = document.querySelector('#button');



canvas.onmousedown = function(event) {
    var x = event.offsetX;
    var y = event.offsetY;
    ctx.strokeStyle = myColor;
    ctx.lineCap = "round";
    ctx.lineWidth = 8;
    ctx.moveTo (x,y);
    canvas.onmousemove = function (event){
        var x = event.offsetX;
        var y = event.offsetY;
        ctx.lineTo(x, y);
        ctx.stroke();
    }
    canvas.onmouseup = function() {
        canvas.onmousemove = null;
    }
};


button.onclick = function (event) {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  ctx.fillRect(10, 10, 400, 250);
};
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="400" height = "250"></canvas>
<button id="button">Clear canvas</button>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var myColor = "#fff";
ctx.fillStyle = "gray";
ctx.fillRect(10, 10, 400, 250);
let clearButton = document.querySelector('#button');



canvas.onmousedown = function(event) {
    var x = event.offsetX;
    var y = event.offsetY;
    ctx.beginPath();

    ctx.strokeStyle = myColor;
    ctx.lineCap = "round";
    ctx.lineWidth = 8;
    ctx.moveTo (x,y);
    canvas.onmousemove = function (event){
        var x = event.offsetX;
        var y = event.offsetY;
        ctx.lineTo(x, y);
        ctx.stroke();
        ctx.stroke();

    }
    canvas.onmouseup = function() {
        canvas.onmousemove = null;
    }
};


button.onclick = function (event) {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  ctx.fillRect(10, 10, 400, 250);
};
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="400" height = "250"></canvas>
<button id="button">Clear canvas</button>
```

Comment: Получается, я забыл beginPath();

Comment: @RafaelShepard отметьте правильным ответ, пожалуйста